# Finding the number of ways numbers can be inserted into the BST

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

The number of ways in which the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 can be inserted in an empty binary search tree, such that the resulting tree has height 4.

(Height of root is 0).

Comment: Have you tried just counting all of them? That's probably what anyone answering this would do anyway. If you're having some trouble with that, it would be better to try to ask a question to improve your understanding of BST's, so you're able to figure out the answer to this question yourself.

Comment: When having only 7 numbers it is 7! = 5040 options which could be done with brute force. Do you search for scale-able solution?

Comment: As mentioned above, maximum height of a BST, is - log(7) base 2 which is 2.80 something, rounding will give you 3. So in short, you can have 7! ways i.e 5040 ways to insert the following numbers in a BST.